# Set a property of collection in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

I would like to know why, when i enter something in the inputTextarea the backing bean will not be updated.
When i print out the result it returns "".
System.out.println(devoir.lstQuestions.get(0).getReponse()); display "";

```
 <ui:repeat  value="#{devoirController.devoir.lstQuestions}"  var="question"  />  
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{question.reponse}" id="reponse">  
    </h:inputTextarea>  
    </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Just an observation - all of those inputTextAreas are going to have the same ID. id="#{question.reponse}"? :-)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, the `#{devoirController}` bean needs to be a `@ViewScoped` bean and the `lstQuestions` needs to be prepopulated in the bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` method. The getter method of `devoir` and `lstQuestions` should absolutely not contain any other line of code than just `return propertyName;`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for this great response, it helped me out.